# Passing parameter from jsp to javascript function at onblur event

Tags: javascript, jsp, onblur

I have a java script function that is used in many jsp files. In general, it is used to validate dates. 
My problem here is that, although its used on many sites, some of them providing different information on how to notify on a failure. Telephone numbers in general.

The date-field itself is embedded in the serviceHeader.jsp:

```html
<h:inputText styleClass="inputText" tabindex="5" id="eventAt"
             value="#{serviceRequest.eventAt}" onblur='leaveFocusDate(this,"<%=telnr %>");'  style="width: 80px;" required="true" >
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
  </h:inputText>
  <h:message for="eventAt" style="color:red; font-family: sans-serif;font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; width: 330px;"/>
```

The serviceHeader.jsp is included in the files that will provide the different informations, for example here in the Canteen.jsp:

```html
<%@include file="serviceHeader.jsp"%>
```

The Canteen.jsp also uses the javascript file:

```html
 <script src='/PersonalWebFormsFrontend/dataSupport.js'
  type='text/javascript'></script>
```

The issue here is that for example the canteen has a different support number then the conference rooms.

I have defined the number for the Canteen.jsp as followed:

```html
<%! String telnr = "-999"; %>
```

The idea is to send a notifiation to the user if the date is invalid. 
The telephone number has to be part of this notification.

Here starts my problem. How can I pass the telnr to the function defined in the dataSupport.js?

Comment: What's the issue? The way you're passing the value right now, is it not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I get the expression instead of the variable: 
<%=telnr %> instead of -999

also, eclipse is showing me the error that telnr cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

The JSF tag `<h:inputText` would not process a JSP expression. You would need to first set the expression value into a scoped variable which can then be accessed by JSF through its own expression language.

```
<c:set var="telnr" value="<%= telnr %>" scope="request" />
<h:inputText ... onblur='leaveFocusDate(this,"#{requestScope.telnr}");' ... />
```